# Making someone unable to do something . .

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a good verb for conveying the meaning of **"making unable"**. For example, it can fill the following blank:
high prices .....  us to buy anything.

Comment: High prices _prohibit_ us from buying.

Comment: I always thought prohibit is more used when something is forbidden by for example law. Can it be used as something that is impossible because of the difficulty?

Answer (score 2):

Preventing.

*High prices prevent us from buying anything.*

Comment: yes that would work. How about "preclude"?